# Logical lock in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, union, sql-insert

Since FUNCCODE is shared between POSCODE and DEVCODE I can't call out both at the same time to eliminate the null values to insert the data into a separate table called JOINT. POSCODE and DEVCODE are FKs. I know there has to be a much easier way of doing this.  I spent the last 2 weeks trying to craft a solution... It feels like I don't understand one thing to make this work. Any advice is appreciated.

Table setup

```
FUNCCODE | POSCODE | DEVCODE

    11        1       NULL
    12       NULL      1
    13        2       NULL 
    14       NULL      2
```

The table needs to be rearranged and then inserted into a separate table called JOINT which is setup as:

```
POSCODE | POSFUNCCODE |DEVCODE | DEVFUNCCODE

   1          11          1         12
   2          13          2         14
```

Some of my attempts XD

Each join creates only 2 of the columns I need

```
SELECT 
    dbo.POSITION.POSCODE AS POSCODE, 
    dbo.FUNC.FUNCCODE AS POSFUNCCODE
FROM FUNC
INNER JOIN POSITION ON dbo.POSITION.POSCODE = dbo.FUNC.POSCODE 

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    dbo.DEVICE.DEVCODE AS DEVCODE,
    dbo.FUNC.FUNCCODE AS DEVFUNCCODE
FROM FUNC
INNER JOIN DEVICE ON dbo.DEVICE.DEVCODE = dbo.FUNC.DEVCODE 
ORDER BY 1;
```

Only inserts the last row values

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME = GETDATE()

DECLARE @PC INT;

SELECT @PC = POSCODE 
FROM func
WHERE poscode != 0 
ORDER BY 1;

DECLARE @FCP INT;

SELECT @FCP = FUNCCODE 
FROM FUNC
WHERE POSCODE != 0 
ORDER BY 1;

DECLARE @DC INT;

SELECT @DC = devcode 
FROM func
WHERE devcode != 0
ORDER BY 1;

DECLARE @FCD INT

SELECT @FCD = FUNCCODE 
FROM FUNC
WHERE DEVCODE != 0
ORDER BY 1

INSERT INTO JOINT (POSCODE, POSFUNCCODE, DEVCODE, DEVFUNCCODE, JOINTTIME,             
JOINTSTATUS)
VALUES (@PC, @FCP, @DC, @FCD, @DATE, 1)
```

Comment: So if `POSCODE=1` then `DEVCODE=1` is how they should match up?

Comment: Also, what version and flavor of SQL?

Comment: @Shawn MS SQL Express 2012, and yes!

Comment: Based on your comment to @user4219031's answer, can you please update the schema in your original question to include POSITION, DEVICE and FUNC tables and how they relate? The original post made it sound like it was all in one table. This is beginning to become an XY Problem. :-S xyproblem.info

Comment: Also, are you trying to get another column out of `POSITION`  or `DEVICE`? Your above query shouldn't need to `JOIN` if all you need is `POSCODE` and `DEVCODE`; those columns are already in `FUNC`. Just query that table directly. I think we need a little more data of the complete problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of your problem is correct, I think the below query would be  a solution.

```
INSERT INTO JOINT (POSTCODE, DEVCODE, POSFUNCCODE, DEVFUNCCODE)
SELECT
POSTCODE,
    DEVCODE,
    MAX(CASE
    WHEN POSCODE IS NOT NULL THEN FUNCCODE
    ELSE NULL
END) POSFUNCCODE,
MAX(CASE
    WHEN DEVCODE IS NOT NULL THEN FUNCCODE
    ELSE NULL
END) DEVFUNCCODE
FROM FUNC
GROUP BY POSTCODE,DEVCODE
```

Second version after a better understanding

```
INSERT INTO JOINT (POSTCODE, DEVCODE, POSFUNCCODE, DEVFUNCCODE)
SELECT
   t1.POSTCODE,
   t2.DEVCODE,
   t1.POSFUNCCODE,
   t2.DEVFUNCCODE
(SELECT
  POSTCODE,
  MAX(CASE
        WHEN POSCODE IS NOT NULL THEN FUNCCODE
        ELSE NULL
    END) POSFUNCCODE
FROM FUNC
GROUP BY POSTCODE) t1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT
  DEVCODE,
  MAX(CASE
        WHEN DEVCODE IS NOT NULL THEN FUNCCODE
        ELSE NULL
END) DEVFUNCCODE
FROM FUNC
GROUP BY DEVCODE) t2
ON t1.POSTCODE = t2.DEVCODE
```

Comment: Thank you for your insight! This does align POSCODE with its FUNCCODE and the DEVCODE with its FUNCCODE, but the insert is staggered by groups leaving large blocks NULL instead of inserting them all together into one row.  This is the logical lock I'm talking about. It only allows one condition for the insert since FUNCCODE is shared between the other two columns.  I tried eliminating the else clause but the grouping remains.  Perhaps there is a way I could perform an update after just one whole column is inserted.  I'll post my solution when I find one. BECAUSE I WILL FIND ONE     XD

Comment: @Brandoncbaldwin - is there a relation between POSTCODE and DEVCODE that will make one record? like one record has the same POSCODE and DEVCODE?

Comment: @Brandoncbaldwin. If there is, I added a second version if the query in the answer

Comment: Trying to resolve the table crisis in my head since POSCODE belongs to table POSITION, DEVCODE belongs to the DEVICE table, and FUNCCODE belongs to the FUNC table. the FUNCCODE needs to be matched with its proper POSCODE and DEVCODE then inserted.  I feel a break through though!

Comment: Against all better judgment I created a loop which inserted the proper values.  Still working on this logic though!

Comment: I would avoid a loop if at all possible. It shouldn't be needed here.

Answer (score 0):

Against my better judgment, I created a loop which inserted the proper values.... I know this is not the correct way to approach this, please excuse me since my experience in SQL is very little. But this corrects the interface issue in the client program. Shout out to @user4219031 for guidance!

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME = GETDATE()

DECLARE @PC INT = 0;

DECLARE  @FCP INT = 12;

DECLARE @DC INT = 0;

DECLARE @FCD INT = 13

WHILE ( @PC < 739 )
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO JOINT (POSCODE, POSFUNCCODE, DEVCODE, DEVFUNCCODE, JOINTTIME, JOINTSTATUS)
   VALUES( @PC, @FCP, @DC, @FCD, @DATE, 1)
    SET @PC = @PC + 1
    SET @FCP = @FCP +2 
    SET @DC = @DC + 1
    SET @FCD = @FCD + 2

END
```

Comment: Make sure to account for edge cases. Also, this relies on magic numbers (`@PC+1`,etc). This can cause all sorts of issues when you move to a live system. These numbers can become inaccurate pretty quickly outside of a test environment.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I changed my query to account for `NULL` `POSCODE` or `DEVCODE`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/76113/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t ( FUNCCODE int, POSCODE int,  DEVCODE int ) ;

INSERT INTO t (FUNCCODE, POSCODE, DEVCODE)
VALUES 
    ( 11, 1, NULL )
  , ( 12, NULL, 1 )
  , ( 13, 2, NULL )
  , ( 14, NULL, 2 )
  , ( 42, NULL, 1 )
  , ( 77, NULL, 7 )
  , ( 88, NULL, 8 )
  , ( 99, 9, NULL )
;
```

**Create New Table And Insert Records**

```
CREATE TABLE ti ( POSCODE int, pos_FUNCCODE int, DEVCODE int, dev_FUNCCODE int ) ;

INSERT INTO ti ( POSCODE, pos_FUNCCODE, DEVCODE, dev_FUNCCODE)
SELECT t1.POSCODE
  , t1.FUNCCODE AS pos_FUNCODE
  , t2.DEVCODE
  , t2.FUNCCODE AS dev_FUNCCODE 
FROM t t1
FULL OUTER JOIN t t2 ON t1.POSCODE = t2.DEVCODE
WHERE t1.POSCODE IS NOT NULL OR t2.DEVCODE IS NOT NULL

;
```

**What's In The New Table?**:

```
SELECT * FROM ti
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/76113/1/0)**:

```
| POSCODE | pos_FUNCCODE | DEVCODE | dev_FUNCCODE |
|---------|--------------|---------|--------------|
|       1 |           11 |       1 |           12 |
|       1 |           11 |       1 |           42 |
|       2 |           13 |       2 |           14 |
|       9 |           99 |  (null) |       (null) |
|  (null) |       (null) |       7 |           77 |
|  (null) |       (null) |       8 |           88 |
```

**==========ORIGINAL==========**

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/76113/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t ( FUNCCODE int, POSCODE int,  DEVCODE int ) ;

INSERT INTO t (FUNCCODE, POSCODE, DEVCODE)
VALUES 
    ( 11, 1, NULL )
  , ( 12, NULL, 1 )
  , ( 13, 2, NULL )
  , ( 14, NULL, 2 )
;
```

**Create New Table And Insert Records**

```
CREATE TABLE ti ( POSCODE int, pos_FUNCCODE int, DEVCODE int, dev_FUNCCODE int ) ;

INSERT INTO ti ( POSCODE, pos_FUNCCODE, DEVCODE, dev_FUNCCODE)
SELECT t1.POSCODE
  , t1.FUNCCODE AS pos_FUNCODE
  , t2.DEVCODE
  , t2.FUNCCODE AS dev_FUNCCODE 
FROM t t1
INNER JOIN t t2 ON t1.POSCODE = t2.DEVCODE
WHERE t1.POSCODE IS NOT NULL
;
```

**What's In The New Table?**:

```
SELECT * FROM ti
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/76113/1/0)**:

```
| POSCODE | pos_FUNCCODE | DEVCODE | dev_FUNCCODE |
|---------|--------------|---------|--------------|
|       1 |           11 |       1 |           12 |
|       2 |           13 |       2 |           14 |
```

Comment: I created another example to account for what appears to be the OP's intent with using 3 separate tables for the `xxxCODE`.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c589e/1  << Only `FUNC` table is needed in the query. No `JOIN` to the other 2 necessary.